# Converting List to new object Map using Lambda Expression Issue

Tags: java, lambda

Java 8 before :

```
final List<SimpleTimerTask> simpleTimerTaskList; // suppose a set of SimpleTimerTask in list
final Map<String, SimpleTTExecutorEntry> result = new HashMap<String, SimpleTTExecutorEntry>();
for (SimpleTimerTask stt: simpleTimerTaskList) {
    SimpleTTExecutorEntry sttEntry = new SimpleTTExecutorEntry(stt, SimpleTimerTaskStatus.Ready, time);
    result.put(stt.getTaskId(), sttEntry);
}
```

Lambda :

```
final Map<String, SimpleTTExecutorEntry> result = simpleTimerTaskList.stream().collect(
Collectors.toMap(
    SimpleTimerTask::getTaskId, SimpleTTExecutorEntry -> 
            new SimpleTTExecutorEntry(SimpleTimerTask, <- error here ->
            SimpleTimerTaskStatus.Ready, time)
));
```

Want to convert the for-loop into Lamdba but SimpleTimer is having object not found error in the SimpleTTExecutorEntry contractor, Can you help to advise, how to correct it, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I just made up an example, just take care of the map() method. You need to use your getters, I just made the "taskId" public. Hope this helps:

```
private void map(){
    List<SimpleTimerTask> simpleTimerTaskList = new ArrayList<>();

    Map<String, SimpleTTExecutorEntry> result = 
        simpleTimerTaskList.stream().collect(
            Collectors.toMap(task -> task.taskId, task -> new SimpleTTExecutorEntry(task, "Status", "time")));
}
// objects similar to yours with the same kind of wrapping
static class SimpleTTExecutorEntry {
    private SimpleTimerTask SimpleTimerTask;
    private Object status;
    private Object time;

    public SimpleTTExecutorEntry(SimpleTimerTask simpleTimerTask, Object status, Object time) {
        SimpleTimerTask = simpleTimerTask;
        this.status = status;
        this.time = time;
    }
}

static class SimpleTimerTask {
    public String taskId;
}
```

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

That works. Thank you very much.

However, I still do not understand, why they must use the same `SimpleTimerTask ->` for `getTaskId()` and `new  SimpleTTExecutorEntry(...)`, Can you help to advise, thanks

```
Collectors.toMap(

SimpleTimerTask -> SimpleTimerTask.getTaskId(),

SimpleTimerTask -> new SimpleTTExecutorEntry(SimpleTimerTask, SimpleTimerTaskStatus.Ready, time))
```